# ReactJS routing always goes to the server

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using ReactJS native and my index.js looks like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <HashRouter>
    <ScrollToTop>
      <App />
    </ScrollToTop>
  </HashRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

The webserver in which this app is running is listening on a context path: **/riskprediction-analysis-ui**

My package.json has this entry:

```
  "homepage": "http://mywebsite.com/riskprediction-analysis-ui",
```

My public/index.html has this one:

```
<base href="/riskprediction-analysis-ui" />
```

My App.js has routes defined as follows:

```
 <Route path="/" exact component={Dashboard} />
 <Route path="/models" component={PredictiveModels} />
 <Route path="/newmodel" component={NewModel} />
 <Route path="/jobs" component={Jobs} />
 <Route path="/analysis-rest-api" component={AnalysisRestApi} />
 <Route path="/ingest-rest-api" component={IngestRestApi} />
 <Route path="/documentation" component={Documentation} />
```

When I start my local development sever using `npm start`, everything looks perfect as I expect it to be. ie everything gets rendered from the client side.

eg: http://localhost:3000/riskprediction-analysis-ui#/models

But when I access this app from a server (I serve it via a java based application) and access it via: http://remote_java_server/riskprediction-analysis-ui#/models
It becomes a server side rendering application ie it goes to the server for every page. This is not what I intended. Anything I'm fundamentally missing here?